# How to reference a react component's state in a redux helper function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I'm new to redux, and I can find lots of info on how to pass a redux state to the component, but not the other way round, so I'm not sure if I'm searching the correct vocabulary. But Essentially I want to be able to reference the current state of a react component in a redux helper function, this is what I've done - and I'm getting `TypeError: dispatch is not a function` and `handleSubmit` is just launching as soon as the page is loaded:

`App.js`

```
render() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>{this.state.id}</p>
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit(this.state.id)}>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispath => bindActionCreators({ 
  handleSubmit
}, dispath);

export default connect(
  mapDispatchToProps  
)(App);
```

`reducers.js`

```
export const handleSubmit = (test) => {
  window.open("http://localhost:5000/"+test);
}

//Reducer
export default (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you don't use the function that `react-redux` pass through the `props` and try to call `handleSubmit` on the component itself.

You are also calling the function inside `onSubmit` immediately instead of passing a reference to a function so wrap it in an arrow function and use `handleSubmit` from `this.props`

`onSubmit={() => this.props.handleSubmit(this.state.id)}`

Second, the first argument to `connect` is the mapping function to get a slice of the state called `mapStateTpProps` by convention, pass in `null` as the first argument.

there is also no need to use `bindActionCreators` and you can just pass an object with functions and `react-redux` will wrap them in `dispatch` for you

```js
export default connect(
  null,
  { handleSubmit }  
)(App);
```

Comment: Thanks! This was a great explanation for me. One thing I had to do was remove the `this.props` for `onSubmit={() => handleSubmit(this.state.id)}` as I was getting "Uncaught Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions."

Answer (score 1):

You need to put id to the state of App and manage it through redux.
Code below will help you.

```
// App.js

render() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>{this.props.id}</p>
      <form onSubmit={this.props.ActionSubmit(this.props.id)}>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}

const mapStateToProps = store => ({
    id: store.appReducer.id,
})

const mapDispatchToProps = dispath => bindActionCreators({ 
  ActionSubmit
}, dispath);

export default connect(
  mapStateToProp,
  mapDispatchToProps  
)(App);

// reducers.js

export ACTION_SUBMIT = 'ACTION_SUBMIT'

export const ActionSubmit = id => ({
    type: ACTION_SUBMIT,
    payload: {
        id,
    }
})

const initialState = {
    id: 0,
}

const doSubmit = (id) => {
  window.open("http://localhost:5000/"+id);
}

export default AppReducer(state = initialState, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case ACTION_SUBMIT:
            doSubmit( action.payload.id)
            return {
                id: action.payload.id,
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```